# Comparing 2 dates in Python did not work as expected

Tags: python

I would like to compare 2 dates in Python. However, the following program does not working as expected. As you can see in the output, today is `2019-08-11`. Unfortunately, Python evaluate it as False even though it's actually true, right?

```
import datetime

today = datetime.date.today()
day1 = datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 11)

print(f"Today's date is {today}")

if today == day1:
    print('today is day1')
else:
    print('today is not day1')
```

**Output**

```
user@linux:~$ py compare2dates.py 
Today's date is 2019-08-11
today is not day1
user@linux:~$
```

What went wrong with this code and how do I fix it?

Comment: Yeah it works. Thanks. Btw, answer can only be accepted after a few minutes .... And not immediately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is simply because you are using `datetime` rather than `date`. If you printed `day1` you would notice it is a datetime with a timestamp:

```
day1 = datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 10)
print(f"day1 is {day1}")
```

> day1 is 2019-08-10 00:00:00

To avoid the error, change your code as follows:

```py
import datetime

today = datetime.date.today()
day1 = datetime.date(2019, 8, 11)

print(f"Today's date is {today}")

if today == day1:
    print('today is day1')
else:
    print('today is not day1')
```